# How can I use either PHP or JavaScript to display the contents of the description meta tag in the body text of a web page?

Tags: javascript, php

My site starts with a class.page.php constructor/destructor that contains the meta info, page title and footer.

```
<?php
class page{
    private $title;
    private $pageDescription;
    
    public function __construct($title, $pageDescription){
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->pagedescription = $pageDescription;

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="My Page Description;">
//  … etc …
    function __destruct()
    {
//  … etc …
    }
}
?>
```

Each page begins with this PHP script to require the class.page.php and insert that page's title and description into the head.

```
<?php
require_once("inc/class.page.php");
// Insert title, page description.
$page = new page('My Page Title','My Page Description');
?>
```

My goal is to be able to insert the description content from the meta tag…

```
<meta name="description" content="I want this also to show up between the h2 tags.">
```

…in between the `h2` tags in the body text, i.e.:

```
<h2>How do I insert the page description here?</h2>
```

I'm able to get the page title to show between the `h1` tags as shown below, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do something similar with the meta description content.

```
<h1 id="pagetitle"></h1>
<script>
    document.getElementById('pagetitle').innerHTML = document.title;
</script>
```

I would prefer to find a PHP solution for this (and for the page title, too, for that matter). but I'd also be happy also to do this using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a `<meta name="description">` element with a `meta[name=description]` selector:

```js
const content = document.querySelector('meta[name=description]').getAttribute('content');
document.getElementById('pagetitle').textContent = content;
```

```html
<meta name="description" content="I want this also to show up between the h2 tags.">
<h1 id="pagetitle"></h1>
```

Also remember to only use `innerHTML` when deliberately inserting HTML markup - if you only want to insert text, use `textContent` instead. (`innerHTML` is less appropriate, slower, and can allow for arbitrary code execution if the content being set isn't trustworthy)